# Using Extent Reports 3.0 version with selenium java, Why all test steps are getting logged in my first test method?

Tags: selenium-extent-report

```
@BeforeSuite
public void setUpConfig()
{
    report = createInstance("TestSummaryReport.html");

    if(properties.ReadPropertiesFile("Browser").equalsIgnoreCase("Chrome"))
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\"+properties.ReadPropertiesFile("ChromeDriver"));
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
    }else if(properties.ReadPropertiesFile("Browser").equalsIgnoreCase("Firefox"))
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\"+properties.ReadPropertiesFile("FirefoxDriver"));
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    }else if(properties.ReadPropertiesFile("Browser").equalsIgnoreCase("IE"))
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\"+properties.ReadPropertiesFile("InternetExplorerDriver"));

        InternetExplorerOptions options = new InternetExplorerOptions();
        options.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.IE_ENSURE_CLEAN_SESSION, true);
        options.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.ELEMENT_SCROLL_BEHAVIOR, 1);
        options.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS, true);
        options.setCapability(CapabilityType.SUPPORTS_JAVASCRIPT, true);
        options.setCapability(CapabilityType.SUPPORTS_FINDING_BY_CSS, true);
        options.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.REQUIRE_WINDOW_FOCUS, true);

        driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(options);
    }

    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    report.setSystemInfo("MachineName", properties.ReadPropertiesFile("MachineName"));
    report.setSystemInfo("IP", properties.ReadPropertiesFile("IP"));
    report.setSystemInfo("OS", properties.ReadPropertiesFile("OS"));
    report.setSystemInfo("Database", properties.ReadPropertiesFile("Database"));
    report.setSystemInfo("ApplicationServer", properties.ReadPropertiesFile("ApplicationServer"));
    report.setSystemInfo("BI Version", properties.ReadPropertiesFile("BIVersion"));
    report.setSystemInfo("QA Build No.", properties.ReadPropertiesFile("QABuild"));
    report.setSystemInfo("Authentication Mode", properties.ReadPropertiesFile("Mode"));
    report.setSystemInfo("Browser", properties.ReadPropertiesFile("Browser"));
}

@BeforeClass
public void beforeClass()
{
    parentTest = report.createTest(getClass().getSimpleName());
}

@BeforeMethod
public void startTestCaseExecution(Method method)
{
    logger = parentTest.createNode(method.getName());
    helper = new Helper(driver, logger);
}

@AfterMethod
public void EndTestCaseExecution(ITestResult result) throws IOException
{   
    if (result.getStatus() == ITestResult.FAILURE)
    {
        TakesScreenshot screen = (TakesScreenshot) driver;
        File src = screen.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
        String screenshotPath = System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\results\\screenshots\\failed\\"+helper.getCurrentDateTime()+"_"+result.getMethod().getMethodName()+".png";
        File target = new File(screenshotPath);
        FileUtils.copyFile(src, target);

        logger.fail(result.getThrowable());
        logger.log(Status.FAIL, "Screenshot : ", MediaEntityBuilder.createScreenCaptureFromPath(screenshotPath).build());
        logger.log(Status.FAIL, MarkupHelper.createLabel(" Test case - "+result.getName()+" FAILED", ExtentColor.RED));
    }
    else if (result.getStatus() == ITestResult.SKIP)
    {
        logger.skip(result.getThrowable());
        logger.log(Status.SKIP, MarkupHelper.createLabel(" Test Case - "+result.getName()+" SKIPPED", ExtentColor.ORANGE));
    }
    else
    {
        logger.log(Status.PASS, MarkupHelper.createLabel(" Test Case - "+result.getName()+" PASSED SUCCESSFULLY", ExtentColor.GREEN));
    }

}

@AfterSuite
public void afterExecution()
 {
     report.flush();

 }
```

// This is my ExtentReportsManager class which i am using in my TesTNg Annotations
    protected static ExtentReports createInstance(String fileName)
    {
        htmlReporter = new ExtentHtmlReporter(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\results\"+getCurrentDateTime()+"_"+fileName);
        htmlReporter.config().setTestViewChartLocation(ChartLocation.TOP);
        htmlReporter.config().setChartVisibilityOnOpen(true);
        htmlReporter.config().setTheme(Theme.STANDARD);
        htmlReporter.config().setDocumentTitle(fileName);
        htmlReporter.config().setEncoding("utf-8");
        htmlReporter.config().setReportName(fileName);
        htmlReporter.setAppendExisting(true);

```
    report = new ExtentReports();
    report.attachReporter(htmlReporter);

    return report;
}

private static String getCurrentDateTime()
{
    Date currentDate = new Date();
    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("E dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    String formattedDate = formatter.format(currentDate);
    String modifiedDate = formattedDate.replace(" ", "_").replace(":", "_");
    return modifiedDate;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you have created single Test Class, So by default it will take all steps under parent class until you don't defined another test class.

Create another test class to keep separation between test method :

```
parentTest = report.createTest("Test Name");
```

Comment: @Alok, Please accept this answer by left side sign, if its useful.

Comment: Thanks Ishita for your suggestion, But can you elaborate the above line of code with a sample code as i have already defined my class dynamically in the before class annotation?

Comment: @Alok What is the issue you are facing as of now ?

Comment: The logs which should get added in the respective test script are getting added in the first test script only.

Comment: So wherever you wants to break the scripts log, create new test section by mentioned syntax.  Let me know if you found any difficulties for same.